# cannot import selenium in new environment Anaconda python 3.6 even though it is installed

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, anaconda, python-3.6

I created a new environment and installed some packages in Anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -n webscap requests scrapy lxml selenium html5lib pandas 
activate webscap
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge 
conda install -n webscap beautifulsoup4
```

I can see the selenium is installed by running `!conda list -n webscap` in jupyter:

```
selenium                  3.9.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

but when I `import selenium` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-612ef00a7e75> in <module>()
----> 1 import selenium

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I even tried to install it again by `conda install -n webscap selenium` but got the same error again. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: I've tested this in python prompt in the new environment without any problem. It's seems in python prompt `sys.path` gives \\Anadonda3\\envs\\webscap\\ while in the jupyter gives `\Anaconda\'. So this means that in the newly created environment I'd be looking at the packages installed at the root environment not the new environment! What I can do about this and why this happens? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else has experienced the same problem, here is what worked for me:
It turned out that in the new environment I created `webscap` I was not able to `import selenium` in jupyter but I was able to do it in python prompt. This happened because the `sys.path` was different in jupyter from python prompt. In jupyter there was no path looking at the `\\envs\\webscap\\`, therefore I need to add the python sys.path to the jupyter sys.path like so:

```
import sys
sys.path
for element in r'C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\python36.zip,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\DLLs,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\lib,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\lib\site-packages,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\lib\site-packages\win32,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\lib\site-packages\win32\lib,C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\webscap\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin'.split(','):
sys.path.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates that you created `webscap` instead of `webscrap` so you need to `activate webscap`:

```
conda create -n webscap requests scrapy lxml selenium html5lib pandas
activate webscap ## you created the env as webscap (not webscrap)
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda install -n webscap beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: That was a typo in stackoverflow. I did it right in my machine. I still have the same problem.

Comment: By the way if you try to activate an environment that does not exist, you'll get at error message.

Comment: What do you get for output if you run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` in your activated webscap environment?

Comment: `['',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Babel-2.5.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\rpy2-2.9.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg',
...

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\uritemplate-3.0.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\zahrae\\.ipython']`

Comment: It appears that it's looking in your main anaconda install, not the activated `webscap`.. It should have something like this in your path that points to your activated forlder. `C:\\Users\\zahrae\\Anaconda3\\envs\\webscap\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'`

Comment: So I don't understand why it can import other packages with this configuration not the selenium? what can I do for selenium?

Comment: if you just do `conda install selenium` in whatever environment it thinks you are in, see if that allows you to import it. Or, close your command prompt, open a new one and run that command, and it will install it in the default anaconda environment.

Comment: The issue still exist. I don't want to install selenium in the base environment though!